# Importing secured content using the jstl import tag and have the OSIV filter working correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, websphere, jstl

Anyone ever tried the following? (and was successful)

In a web application (A), I am using the `<c:import>` tag to get secured content from another web application (B) running on the same application server (WebSphere 7). Both apps use Hibernate and Spring's OSIV filter.

Looking at the import tag source, I see that the strategy is that if the url is relative then it includes the content using `RequestDispatcher.include()`  .If the url is absolute, the code opens a `URLConnection`.

Since I need to keep track of the remote user, I can't do the following:

`<c:import url="http://host:port/B/getContent">`

Doing

`<c:import url="/getContent" context="/B">`

instead would work. But with this approach I am not hitting Spring's OSIV filter configured in B. The original (importing) request in A does go through the OSIV filter but it has no effect in B. Hence I am getting the usual "No session or session closed" error for lazy initializations of entities.

I am bit in a catch 22 here and I am wondering if what I am trying to do is actually feasable according to my requirements.

The bottom line is that I did manage to get what I wanted by aggregating my content directly from the client using Dojo, (I am using SSO so the identity of the user gets carried) but I would prefer the other way if it was possible.